# Dynamically adding paper_trail to translations in Rails5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, paper-trail-gem, globalize3

I have an application that translates some model data and I would like to version this data. So this is my setup:

- Rails 5.1.4
- Ruby 2.4.1 (with RVM)
- Globalize @ master
- PaperTrail for versioning of the translations

I have created a [pull-request](https://github.com/globalize/globalize-versioning/pull/16) that should add rails 5 functionality to the [globalize-versioning gem](https://github.com/globalize/globalize-versioning).

I already did this:

- Update the gemspec and the Gemfile to use the latest gems.
- Fix deprecated ruby calls
- Update the `.travis.yml` so that tests are run.

Now all tests in the projects fail and I can't quite figure out how to add the paper_trail functionality to the translations objects from globalize.

Comment: I am "merely" a user of `paper_trail` and `globalize` and `globalize-versioning` so I am a bit overwhelmed with the concept of how the functionality gets injected into these different models.

Answer (score 2):

You changed the `alias_method_chain` wrongly.

```
alias_method :versioning, :setup_translates!
alias_method :setup_translates!, :versioning
```

This only aliases versioning and setup_translates!. What `alias_method_chain` actually tries is to make sure a overriden method is still callable.

So this:

```
alias_method_chain :setup_translates!, :versioning
```

should be changed to:

```
alias_method :setup_translates_without_versioning!, :setup_translates!
alias_method :setup_translates!, :setup_translates_with_versioning!
```

Try if this solves the issues.

source: [alias_method_chain](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/alias_method_chain)